# Force UTF8 encoding in html form with Spring MVC Web Application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, utf-8, tomcat8, forms, http-post

I have a spring MVC web application and using JSPs to create my web pages.
The problem is that when I directly submit a form the encoding is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". When I submit the same data from the same form via an AJAX-Request the encoding is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8".

I need the utf8 encoded characters typed in be a user in my controller. For example: A user types "äöüß" my controller gets "Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã". When I send the data via an AJAX-Request I get "äöüß" which is correct.

What am I doing wrong? This is a simple form submit via http-post. It can't be impossible to do this utf8 encoded.

My application is running on a tomcat 8.5.11 with Spring 5.0.1. The web pages are all in HTML5 and I use the JSTL 1.2.5 in a servlet 3.1 environment. The JSON mapping and serialization is done by fasterxml 2.9.2

The configuration is completely Java-based.

My WebAppInitializer (a.k.a. web.xml)

```
...
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] { new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(), 
                            new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-8", true, true) };
}
```

In my servlet config I explicitly set a charset for the StringHttpMessageConverter.

```
...
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```

The Webpage looks like

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page session="true" %>
<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="de">

...

<meta charset="UTF-8"/>

...

<form id="createArticleForm" action="<c:url value='/article/save' />" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="&#x2713;" />

...

  <input type="text" name="name" required="required" />

...
</form>
```

As you can see I also tried the utf8 hacks with a hidden field. But nothing works. Even if I set the form attributes accept-charset="UTF-8" and/or encoding="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" nothing changes.

**Edit1**
I checked the HTTP Request Header sent from the browser to the server. And I found out that all parameters are correct. So I assume a spring configuration problem.

Comment: `accept-charset` should be added and: `<input value="\u2713">`

Comment: @Joop As I wrote. This is not working.

Comment: I understood, but _"And that is what I need."_ is rather inflexible. What is the error? I thought you still got non-ASCII characters as numeric entities `&#...;` - hence my rewrite of `\u2713`

Comment: For example: I type the name "äöüß" in the form and I want these characters to be received by my controller. But instead I recieve "Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã". No error but the wrong result. And the difference to an AJAX-request is the content-type where explicitly the charset is set in the AJAX-Request while it's not with the normal form submission.

Comment: Then the client sends the data in UTF-8 but the server assumes the answering request to be in something like Latin-1. That might be configuration or filters, but you need someone else for that, I must go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The problem lies in the initialiation of the characterEncodingFilter.

In a web.xml you do the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Since with Spring 5 Java-based Annotation Configuration is favored, according to the documentation you can do the following in your WebApplicationInitializer which is much simpler than the code above:

```
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] { new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(), 
                            new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-8", true, true) };
}
```

**BUT** this is **NOT** working properly with every HttpRequest coming in!!!

The solution is to **not use the provided convenient way** to automatically map the  filter to the servlet.

Instead you must:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

      FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter("UTF-8", true, true));
      filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

      filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter() );
      filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    super.onStartup(servletContext);
}
```

And here you have your filter mapping back in sight and this works perfect!